# How can i decorate Google Test fixture

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have some test:

```
class Somefixture: ::testing::Test{};
class Somefixture2: ::testing::Test{};

TEST_F(SomeFixture, SomeName)
{
// ...
}
```

How can i automatically link test to both fixtures (decorate)?

```
TEST_F2(SomeFixture, SomeFixture2, SomeName){}
```

While the required result will be as if I wrote:

```
TEST_F(SomeFixture, SomeName)
{
// ...
}
TEST_F(SomeFixture2, SomeName)
{
// ...
}
```

Without the unnecessary code duplication

Answer (score 1):

With one little exception (two tests can't have the same name), this should go in the right derection:

```
#define TEST_F2(F1, F2, Name)                                  \
template <struct Fixture> struct MyTester##Name : Fixture {    \
  void test##Name();                                           \
};                                                             \
                                                               \
TEST_F(MyTester##Name<F1>, Name##1){ test##Name(); }           \
TEST_F(MyTester##Name<F2>, Name##2){ test##Name(); }           \
                                                               \
template <struct Fixture> void MyTester##Name::test##Name()
```

This will call two tests, each using MyTester as fixture that inherits from one of the two fixtures. Since do_test is a member of MyTester, it has access to all inherited members from the fixtures. The test framework will create an MyTester object for each test and the corresponding actual fixture will get created as base class object. To avoid naming conflicts with other tests or bewteen different calls of TEST_F2, I appended the Name to the template name and test method name. The TEST_F macro calls are supplied with a name and an index. I did not test it, since I don't have Google Test, but the mechanisms in many of those testing frameworks work similar.

Comment: thanks, but this is a little bit ugly variant (must be framework). it's a normal practice to use decorators for unit tests.

Comment: Define "normal practice" - I don't know any decorators in Google Test.

Comment: there is a such "decorator" in NUnit. and i think in java, python, ruby must be too..

Comment: Well, but this is Google Test and C++, so you can't just assume from those other languages and frameworks. However, you might want to have a look at CppUnit which is a C++ port of NUnit. FWIW, the Google.Test macros behind TEST_F look very similar (and ugly) to what I did above, and with the lack of reflection and the presence of static typing and other stuff, that's pretty normal practice in C++ unit test frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i automatically link test to both fixtures (decorate)?

By adding a common base class :

```
class CommonFixture
{
  public:
    // add member variables and initialize them in the constructor
};
class Somefixture1 : ::testing::Test, protected CommonFixture{}
class Somefixture2 : ::testing::Test, protected CommonFixture{}
```

Tests stay the same :

```
TEST_F(SomeFixture1, SomeName)
{
// ...
}
TEST_F(SomeFixture2, SomeName)
{
// ...
}
```

Now you got a common fixture for Somefixture1 and Somefixture2. You can access these common objects from within your tests.

Comment: And how should i call my test to make it body in single instance, but called with both 1 and 2 fixtures?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `BЈовић` approach which seems good.
Or anther approach which required a small change to the test itself can be having a "super" class which will have both instances as members.

```
class superFuxture
{
public:
    Somefixture1 f1;
    Somefixture2 f2;
}
```

Then you test will be like that:

```
TEST_F(superFuxture, SomeName)
{
    //when you were accessing a member of Somefixture1 you'll now need to do:
    //f1.SomeFixture1Member
}
```

Comment: i have 20 tests. and i want to pass them with both 1 and 2 fixture. and i don't want to copy-paste test code.

Comment: @Deeptowncitizen: I'm not sure I get what you want. do you want the test to run once with `someFuxture` and then again with `someFixture2`?

Comment: In that case my previous answer is not relevant and I've edit the question to make it more seance. I'll try to think of a way to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Google Test has two ways of executing the same test body in different contexts: [value-parameterized tests](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Value_Parameterized_Tests) or [typed/type-parameterized tests](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Typed_Tests). Not precisely what you want but it's the closest thing it offers.